# Hardy-Littlewood maximal function inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Question:
Let $f^\ast$ be the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of $f$ and let $w(x)$ be a nonnegative function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose there exists constants $C_1, C_2 >0$ so that
$$\int_{\{f^\ast > t\}} w(x) \, dx \leq C_1 \frac{\int |f(x)| w(x) \, dx}{t}, \quad \forall t >0$$
and
$$\int |f^\ast(x)|^2 w(x) \, dx \leq C_2 \int |f(x)|^2 w(x) \,dx $$ for all locally integrable functions $f$. Show that for each $1 < p < 2$, there exists a constant $C_3>0$ so that
$$\int |f^\ast(x)|^p w(x) \, dx \leq C_3 \int |f(x)|^p w(x) \, dx.$$

My attempt: Define $\mu(dx)= |w(x)| \,dx$ as a positive regular Borel measure. Using the the layer-cake representation of integral and definition of the maximal function, I have obtained the following inequality
$$\int_{ \{f^\ast > 1\}} |f^\ast|^p \, d\mu(x) \leq \int_{\{f > 1\}}|f|^p \, d \mu(x)$$
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\{f^\ast > 1\}} |f^\ast|^p \, d \mu(x) &\leq \left(\int_{\{f^\ast > 1\}} |f^\ast|^2  \right)^{p/2} \left( \int_{\{f^\ast > 1\}} \, d \mu(x) \right)^{1 - p/2}\\
&\leq \left( \int_{\{f^\ast > 1\}} |f^\ast|^2 \, d \mu(x) \right)^{p/2} \cdot C_1 \Vert f \Vert_{L^1_\mu(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{1 - p/2}\\
&\leq C_1 C_2 \Vert f \Vert_{L^2_\mu(\mathbb{R}^n)}^p \Vert f \Vert_{L^1_\mu(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{1 - p/2}
\end{align*}

However, I am unable to proceed from here. Any hints/solutions are appreciated.